# Error C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that take vectors and modify them 
 but it  gives me Error:
 ***" variable 'Vector' is not a type name"***

I'm new to c++ overloaded operators so their might be a lot of syntax error

whats the problem here, is it in the functions declaration or the implementation

another thing ,when do I use const with parameters ?

```
class Vector{
private:
    int n;
    int *vArray;
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(int);
    ~Vector();
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is , Vector &v );
    friend ostream& operator>>(ostream& os  , const Vector &v);
    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& );
    Vector operator+(Vector& rhs);
    double operator*(Vector&);
    Vector operator-(Vector);

};

Vector::Vector(){
    n = 2;
    vArray = new int[n];

}


Vector::Vector(int num){
    n = num;
    vArray = new int[n];
}

Vector::~Vector(){
    delete [] vArray;


}


istream& operator>>(istream& is, Vector& v){
    for (int i = 0; i < v.n; i++)
        is >> v.vArray[i];
    return is;

}
ostream& operator>>(ostream& os, const Vector& v){
    for (int i = 0; i < v.n; i++)
        os >> v.vArray[i];
    return os;


}

Vector& :: Vector operator+=(const Vector& rhs){
    if(n == rhs.n){
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            this->vArray[i] += rhs.vArray[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
    cout << "Error: size not match" << endl;
}

Vector:: Vector operator+( Vector& rhs){
    if (n == rhs.n){
        Vector z(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            z.vArray[i] = this->vArray[i] + rhs.vArray[i];

       return z;
    }
    cout << "Error: size not match"<<endl;


}


double::Vector operator* (Vector& v){
    double count;
    if (n == v.n){
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            count += this->vArray[i] * v.vArray[i];
        }
        return count;

    }
    cout << "Error: size not match";

}


Vector::Vector operator-(Vector v){
    if (n == v.n){
        Vector z(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        z.vArray[i]=this->vArray[i]-v.vArray[i];

    }
    return z;
}
    cout << "Error: size not match" << endl;

}
```

Comment: You didn't post the line where the error occurs. Also, any good reason not to use std::vector?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You shouldn't ask "what's wrong" on Stack Overflow - instead, you tell us what's wrong, and ask how to fix it. Someone will usually help you fix the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Where is `#include <vector>`?

Comment: What was the last change you made before the error appeared? If you wrote all of this without testing any of it, you were asking for failure. Start small and simple, build up slowly, test at every step.

Comment: Another thing: one question per Question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few errors here, on the following lines:

```
Vector& :: Vector operator+=(const Vector& rhs){
Vector& :: Vector operator+=(const Vector& rhs){
Vector:: Vector operator+( Vector& rhs){
double::Vector operator* (Vector& v){
Vector::Vector operator-(Vector v){
```

These should be:

```
Vector& Vector::operator+=(const Vector& rhs){
Vector& Vector::operator+=(const Vector& rhs){
Vector Vector::operator+( Vector& rhs){
double Vector::operator* (Vector& v){
Vector Vector::operator-(Vector v){
```

The not a typename error is probably from the `Vector::Vector` one since you should be returning a type and not identifying the constructor of Vector.

Also, your vector class does not define/delete a copy constructor or an assignment operator.  If you copy instances of this class then it will use the default copy/assign which will simply copy the value of the pointer member and not perform a deep copy -- you will end up with double-deletes which will crash your program.

And for the const parameter question..  You should use a const reference whenever the function does not modify the value passed in.  Also if the function does not modify objects of the class themselves, the member function should be const also.
For example, operator+ should accept a const parameter and also itself be const:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(Vector const& rhs) const
```

It is good practice to use const wherever possible - it is generally easier to relax a restriction than to add one retrospectively.

Take a look at this:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html

Comment: that solve the problem ,I guess I should read the code carefully